# Text mining .docx interview transcriptions in R

Tags: r, text-mining, .doc, transcription, tidytext

I have a number of interview transcriptions that I am hoping to run text mining analyses on. Basically trying to automate the qualitative coding procedure.

I've been reading up on [tidytext](http://tidytextmining.com/) text mining, but it only seems to use already imported datasets! How do I actually import a .docx file into R to start using tidytext functions?

I found a package from Github ([textreadr](https://github.com/trinker/textreadr)) that says it can import transcripts, but I can't quite follow the commands used to load the data.

Comment: Never mind, I got the textreadr package to work! Don't know how to delete this question, but if anyone else wants to know, textreadr seems to work for importing text document.